# Azure Database for PostgreSQL flexible server sudden drop of "Memory Percent"

Tags: postgresql, azure

[image]

Suddenly my hosted application became slow the same day in which Memory Percent dropped

Comment: We have no idea what your application does, what has changed, what so ever. Please share some information or close the question, nobody can help you with just one image

Comment: Do you need an understanding of why it behaves like that @hashem? since the info we got was limited we can only share with you potential reasons for the cause.